# PCA questions about orthogonal, eigenvector and Radial basis NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

1. If one wishes to transform a data set into a different, orthogonal coordinate system of lower
   dimension, what is the most important coordinate direction to have in the new coordinate
   system?
2. The relation between the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the data set and the
   coordinate transformation that minimizes data loss?
3. Provide the architecture, processing formulae, and learning rule for a neural network that
   computes the eigenvector with highest eigenvalue in the covariance matrix of a data set.
4. Explain the unique properties of the Radial Basis Neural Network.

These are the question I meet in class, left as thinking problem

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no code given, just left these to think. That's why I'm confused and trying to ask here.